# How to implement a function plotter

Tags: graphics, plot, geometry, 2d, ocaml

I have to implement a simple 2D function plotter using the OCaml language. I get the general idea. So far the strategy would be to have a function, lets call it plot, that will eventually map a given input function f to a visualisation of f. So far, I'd like to think that the visualisation is a curve that's a set of vertices with the following coordinates for x and y, x is varying along the horizontal axis and y the value of f(x). The first step would be calculate the of vertices and store it somewhere and proceed to draw each point. Only, for visualization purposes this is way to much information to calculate and invokes several problems : what ratio are we going to use, how many values can x have, how much vertices are going to be calculated and how much vertices we need to draw the actual curve?. So I'm a little bit lost regarding the appropriate strategy for plotting curves of functions. Could someone please give me some ideas or simple template so I can elaborate on? Or examples for a given function like x^2.

Here's some code that I produced using lablgl and GLUT since I had the intention on implementing a 3D plotter as well, it plots the function f(x) = sin(x*10) / (1+x^2).

```
open Gl;;
open GlMat;;
open GlDraw;;
open GlClear;;
open Glut;;

(* Transform RGB values in [0.0 - 1.0] to use it with OpenGL *)

let oc = function
    x -> float x /. 255.
;;

(* The function to be graphed *)

let expression = function
    x -> sin (10. *. x) /. (1. +. x *. x)
;;


(* The rendering function drawing 2000 points in 400x400 canvas *)

let display () =
  GlClear.color (oc 255, oc 255,oc 255);
  clear [`color];
  load_identity ();
  begins `lines;
  GlDraw.color (oc 0, oc 0, oc 0);
  List.iter vertex2 [-1.,0.; 1.,0.];
  List.iter vertex2 [0.,-1.;0.,1.];
  ends ();
  begins `points;
  for i=0 to 2000  do
    let  x = (float i -. 1000.) /. 400. in
    let y = expression (x)  in 
    vertex2 (x,y);
  done;
  ends ();
  swapBuffers ();
  flush();
;;

(* general stuff and  main loop *)

let () =
  ignore (init Sys.argv);
  initWindowSize ~w:400 ~h:400;
  initDisplayMode ~double_buffer:true ();
  ignore (createWindow ~title:"Sin(x*10)/(1+x^2)");
  mode `modelview;
  displayFunc ~cb:display;
  idleFunc ~cb:(Some postRedisplay);
  keyboardFunc ~cb:(fun ~key ~x ~y -> if key=27 then exit 0);
  mainLoop ()
;;
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: better if you show some effort/code first

Comment: Oh ok, I've tried using lablgl and glut since I planned on implementing a 3D plotter later on so I'm not sure it's adequate but I will add it anyway @EdgarAroutiounian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys here it is implemented a plotter that works fairly well, ignore the zoom feature it really doesn't work and I still have a problem with illegal values if someone ever has a hint, I'll be glad!

```
open Graphics

type vis_zoom = {mutable z:float}

type vis_unit = {mutable au:int; mutable ou:int}

type range = { mutable abs : int * int; mutable ord : int * int}

(* Facteur zoom courrant *)
let czoom = {z = 1.}

(* L'unité graphique courrante en pixels,
   respectivement, pour les abscisse et
   les ordonnees *)
let cunit = { au = 50; ou = 50} 


(* Les rang d'évaluation de la fonction *)
let crange = {abs = (-5,5); ord = (-5,5)}

let fint x = float_of_int x

let ifloat x = int_of_float x

let set_unit u =
  cunit.au <- (fst u);
  cunit.ou <- (snd u)

let set_range amin amax omin omax =
  crange.abs <- (amin, amax);
  crange.ord <- (omin, omax)

let set_zoom z = 
  czoom.z <- z;
  let amin = ifloat ((fint (fst crange.abs)) *. z) and
    amax = ifloat ((fint (snd crange.abs)) *. z) and
    omin = ifloat ((fint (fst crange.ord)) *. z) and
    omax = ifloat ((fint (snd crange.ord)) *. z) in
  crange.abs <- (amin, amax);
  crange.ord <- (omin, omax)


(* Permet de dire si un nombre flotant est nan,
   not a number, ou pas  *)
let is_nan = function x -> (not (x < 0.) && not( x >= 0.))

(* Retourne une liste d'entiers qui représente
   le rang défini par les bornes d'un couple d'entiers r*)

let rec range_list r =
  match r with
    (f,l) when f > l -> []
  | (f,l) -> f:: range_list (f+1,l)

(* Modifie la taille de l'unité graphique
   en fonction de la taille de la fenêtre et
des range d'évaluation *)

let rel_unit a o =
  let x = List.length a and
  y = List.length o in
  let au = (size_x ()) / x and
  ou = (size_y ()) / y in
  set_unit (au,ou)


(* Détérmine les coordonnées graphiques de l'origine 0,0 *)
let make_origin () =
  let zabs = cunit.au/2 - cunit.au * fst crange.abs and
    zord = cunit.ou/2 - cunit.ou * fst crange.ord in
  (zabs,zord)

(* Dessine les graduation d'un axe *)

let rec draw_marks marks xoff yoff xpace ypace zabs zord = match marks with
  |[] -> ()
  |0::t ->
    draw_marks t xoff yoff xpace ypace zabs zord
  |h::t ->
    begin
      let x = zabs + (h * xpace) and
      y = zord + (h * ypace) in
      if
        (0 <= x) && (x <= (size_x ())) &&  (0 <= y) && (y <= (size_y ()))
      then
        begin
          moveto (x - xoff) (y + yoff);
          lineto (x + (1 * xoff)) (y - (1 * yoff));
          moveto (x + (3 * xoff)) (y - (3 * yoff));
          draw_string (string_of_int h);
          draw_marks t xoff yoff xpace ypace zabs zord
        end
      else
        draw_marks t xoff yoff xpace ypace zabs zord
    end

(* Dessine les axes des ordonnées et des abscisses
 avec les graduations *)

let draw_axis () =
  let abs_range = range_list (crange.abs) and
  ord_range = range_list (crange.ord) in
  rel_unit abs_range ord_range;
  let origin = make_origin ()in
  let zabs = fst origin and
    zord = snd origin in
  set_color black;
  moveto 0 zord;
  lineto (size_x ()) zord;
  moveto zabs zord;
  draw_marks abs_range 0 5 cunit.au 0 zabs zord;
  moveto zabs 0;
  lineto zabs (size_y ());
  moveto zabs zord;
  draw_marks ord_range 5 0 0 cunit.ou zabs zord


(* Algroithme de rafinement entre deux point p et p'
   par rapport a l'origine *)

let rec refine x y x' y' zabs zord (f:float -> float)=
  let x'' = ((x' - x) / 2) + x and
  y'' = ((y' - y) / 2) + y and
  f_of_x = f ((fint (x- zabs)) /. (fint cunit.au)) and
  f_of_x' = f ((fint (x'- zabs)) /. (fint cunit.au)) in
  let true_y = zord + (ifloat (f ((fint (x''- zabs)) /. (fint cunit.au)) *. (fint cunit.ou))) and
  f_of_x'' = f (((fint x'') -. (fint zabs)) /. (fint cunit.au)) in 
  if abs (true_y - y'') > 0 && (x''-x) >= 1
  then
    begin
      refine x y x'' true_y zabs zord f;
      refine x'' true_y x' y' zabs zord f;
    end
  else if  not (is_nan f_of_x) && not (is_nan f_of_x') && not (is_nan f_of_x'')
           && (0 <= y) && (y <= (size_y ())) && (0 <= y') && (y' <= (size_y ()))
  then
    begin
      begin
        if
          f_of_x = infinity
        then
          moveto x (size_y ())
        else if
          f_of_x = neg_infinity
        then
          moveto x 0
        else
          moveto x y
      end;
      begin
        if
          f_of_x' = infinity
        then
          lineto x' (size_y ())
        else if
          f_of_x' = neg_infinity
        then
          lineto x' 0
        else
          lineto x' y'
      end;
    end
  else
    ()

(* Dessine la courbe d'une fonction passé en paramètre *)

let rec draw_curve (f:float -> float) =
  set_color blue;
  let rec aux abslist zabs zord  = match abslist with
    |[] -> ()
    |a::b::t ->
      begin
        let x = zabs + (a * cunit.au) and
        y = zord + (ifloat ((f (fint a)) *. (fint cunit.ou))) and
        x' = zabs + (b * cunit.au) and
        y' = zord + (ifloat ((f (fint b)) *. (fint cunit.ou))) in
        refine x y x' y' zabs zord f;
        aux (b::t) zabs zord
      end
    |h::[] -> ()
  and origin = make_origin () in
  let zabs = fst origin and
  zord = snd origin  in
  let  abs = range_list (crange.abs)
  in
  aux abs zabs zord

let zoomin () =
  let z = (czoom.z -. 0.25) in
  set_zoom z

let zoomout () =
  let z = (czoom.z +. 0.25) in
  set_zoom z

let move dx dy =
  let offx = dx / cunit.au and
  offy = dy / cunit.ou in
  let amin = (fst crange.abs) - offx and
    amax = (snd crange.abs) - offx and
    omin = (fst crange.ord) - offy and
    omax = (snd crange.ord) - offy in
  crange.abs <- (amin,amax);
  crange.ord <- (omin,omax)


(* Boucle principale de la courbe pour la déplacer ou zoomer *)

let rec loop f =
  draw_axis ();
  draw_curve f;
  let e = wait_next_event [Key_pressed; Button_down] in
  if e.button then
    let fx = e.mouse_x and
    fy = e.mouse_y and
    se = wait_next_event [Button_up] in
    let sx = se.mouse_x and
      sy = se.mouse_y in
    let dx = sx - fx and
      dy = sy - fy in
    move dx dy;
    clear_graph ();
    draw_axis ();
    draw_curve f;
    loop f
  else if e.keypressed then
    if e.key = 'i'
    then
      begin
        zoomin ();
        clear_graph ();
        draw_axis ();
        draw_curve f;
        loop f
      end
    else if e.key = 'o'
    then
      begin
        zoomout ();
        clear_graph ();
        draw_axis ();
        draw_curve f;
        loop f
      end
    else if e.key = 'q'
    then ()
      else loop f
  else
    loop f

(* Fonction qui ouvre une fenêtre et dessine, les axes
 dans les intervales [amin,amax] et [omin, omax] *)

let gplot (f: float -> float) amin amax omin omax =
  open_graph " 800x600+200-200";
  set_window_title "Plot";
  set_range amin amax omin omax;
  loop f;
  close_graph ()

(* Fonction équivalente a gplot mais dans les intervals
 par défaut [-5,5] et [-5,5] *)

let plotd (f: float -> float) =
  gplot f (-5) 5 (-5) 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to select the ranges for X and Y automatically, as this is strongly function-dependent and requires a true understanding of the function behavior. (It is also subjective to a large extent.)

So the easiest way is to leave this as user-adjustable parameters, with suitable default values (say [-5,5]x[-5,5]).

An important issue is the aspect ratio: you will be drawing in a rectangle called a Viewport; if the ratio of the sides of this rectangle doesn't match the ratio of the X and Y ranges for the function (this is called the Window), the curve will be deformed. A circle will appear as an ellipse.

Depending on the cases, it matters or not to ensure equality of the aspect ratios. You should leave that as a user option. In case yes, your software should adjust the Window limits to fit.

Regarding the point density, you can use the following strategy: choose a fixed number of points horizontally (say 100). With such a step, the line segments will be discernible. Then you can use a recursive subdivision process to get a smooth drawing: considering a line segment, compute a point midway of the endpoints and evaluate the distance of the true curve point to the line segment. If it exceeds a threshold, split the segment in two and repeat with both halves. Be sure to perform the computation after conversion to Viewport coordinates, so that all values are in pixels.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your ideas! I will give this a try. It seems to make a lot of sense! @Yves Daoust

Answer (score 2):

Using [archimedes](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/archimedes/archimedes.0.4.17/) library, you can plot your function `f` as simple as `A.fx vp f 0. 10.`. But let's go step by step, starting with the installation.

1. Install archimedes via opam

   ```
   opam install archimedes
   ```
2. Start toplevel

   ```
   ocaml
   ```
3. Load topfind

   ```
   # #use "topfind";;
   ```
4. Load archimedes library:

   ```
   # #require "archimedes";;
   ...
   Module Archimedes loaded and aliased as A.
   ```
5. Start to play:

   ```
   let f x = sin (x *. 10.) /. ( 1. +. x**2.);;
   let vp = A.init ["graphics"; "hold"];;
   A.Axes.box vp;;
   A.fx vp f 0. 10.;;
   A.close vp;;
   ```
6. Look at what you've done
   [image]